# RingCentral Connect and Retrieve Call Log Details from Server via Java Code?

Tags: java, rest, calllog, ringcentral

I want to develop a Java Application that will connect to RingCentral and retrieve Call Log details from the RingCentral Server.

Can anyone help me make a RingCentral app with right permissions and client-side Java code details?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following resources will help get you started on developing an app in Java to retrieve call log records using the [RingCentral API](https://developers.ringcentral.com).

1. App Dev Guide on creating an app

   - https://developers.ringcentral.com/library/tutorials/app-development.html
2. API Guide on Call Log Resource

   - http://ringcentral-api-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/calllog_introduction/
3. Java sample code for retrieving call log records

   - https://github.com/vyshakhbabji/ringcentral-CallLog-Recording-Downloader
4. Java SDK

   - https://github.com/vyshakhbabji/ringcentral-java

Comment: Hi , In your Option no 3.Java sample code for retrieving call log records  -- there is no jar files included on github, can u help me to find the jars..

Comment: There is a JAR on the [repo releases page](https://github.com/vyshakhbabji/ringcentral-CallLog-Recording-Downloader/releases). I see you've asked on the [repo's issues page](https://github.com/vyshakhbabji/ringcentral-CallLog-Recording-Downloader/issues) which is the right place to ask.

Comment: Hi I have email you in details , my problem, I am getting the error . Error Message: HTTP Status Code 400 Bad Request

Comment: For email support, please email devsupport@ringcentral.com